# Plotting parametric equations in Maple

Tags: graphing-functions, maple, computer-algebra-systems

I have the following problem. Let $\alpha:=\alpha(v)$ and $\beta:=\beta(v)$, where $v\in\mathbb{R}$. Using MAPLE, I would like to plot $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the $(\alpha,\beta)$ space as $v$ varies continuously. I suspect that this will involve creating lists in Maple. I need some help! Here is what I am thinking at this time:

```
restart:

alpha:=v-> some function of v:
beta:=v-> some function of v:

for v from 0.01 to 10 by 0.001 do
  alpha:=alpha(v):
  beta:=beta(v):
  ? put the alpha and beta into a list?
od:

?plot the sequence of points in the list?
```

I need some direction/help from Maple users out there, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot([alpha(v),beta(v),v=0..10]);
```

No manual lists required.

Comment: Thanks! How does one include the stepsize 0.001 in the "v=0..10"? Another question: When using the display function (for multiple plots), is it possible to write the resulting figure into a file, like it's done with plot and plotsetup? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can plot a list of points (where each 2D point is represented as a list),

```
restart:
alpha:=v->sin(v):
beta:=v->cos(v):

plot([seq([alpha(v),beta(v)], v=0.01..10.0, 0.001)]);
```

Or you could make a parametric plot, optionally forcing the number of points if you wish,

```
restart:
alpha:=v->sin(v):
beta:=v->cos(v):

plot([alpha(t),beta(t),t=0.01..10.0]);

plot([alpha(t),beta(t),t=0.01..10.0],adaptive=false,numpoints=9991);
```

See also the [plot,parametric](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plot/parametric) help-page.